# How to obtain estimates for all levels in a mixed effects model that uses effect (deviation) coding?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding

I am running a binomial mixed effects logistic regression in R using `glmer` for a sociolinguistics project. I was asked to used deviation (effect) coding. From what I gather, in deviation coding the last level in a factor is assigned -1, because this is the level that is never compared to the other levels within that variable. Is it possible to obtain the `Estimate` (`Exp(B)` value) for the last level as well by using function `relevel`? I need to report the estimates for all the levels.

For example, my model has the independent variable called **Orthography** with four levels (`s`, `sh`, `s1`, `sh1`). The dependent variable is **produced sibilant**. In deviation coding the fourth level (`sh1`) will not be compared to the other three levels, and estimates will be available for the first three (`s`, `sh`, `s1`). The intercept is the mean of the means of all four levels (`s + sh + s1 + sh1 / 4`). I am interested in obtaining the estimate for the last level (`sh1`) as well. Does anyone know how to get that? Do I have to rerun the model by changing levels? If so, does anyone know how to do that? I have been unsuccessful with using function `relevel` to do this.

I have other terms in my model as well:

- following segment, which has two levels (`vowel`, `consonant`),
- position of sibilant in word (`initial`, `medial`, `final`),
- grammatical function (`noun`, `verb`, `adjectives`), and
- language of instruction (`English`, `Gujarati`).

This is the code for my model:

```
model.final_si = glmer(prod_sib ~ orthography + foll_segment + word_position + 
                                  grammatical_func + language_instruction + 
                                  (1|participant) + (1|item), 
                       family="binomial",data=data)
```